# How get a list of files under a subversion-url in ant?

Tags: svn, ant, svnant

I want with ant access a subversion-repository and get a list of files available under a specific svn-url like https://svn.myhost.de/repository/path/into/repo. I want to list all items, subdirectories or files, in some form I can work with later in the ant-file. A comma-separated list is fine, it can be input for the foreach-task of ant-contrib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Subclipse Project](http://subclipse.tigris.org) of Subversion provides [svnant](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html)

[svnant](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html) includes `svnFileSet`, an `ant type` that works just like a `fileset`.

You need to download the appropriate version for the Subversion release you're using, and follow the instructions in the documentation for including the `svnant` tasks, types, selectors and conditions in your `ant` build file.

Comment: svnant does not appear to support the list command.
and svnfileset is for working copy.. not url